# Instalar qt con Visual Studio

Tags: qt

Quiero instalar qt con Visual Studio. Quiero usar la version msvc2013 pero no se cual version de visual studio bajar por favor me podrian decir cual es la correcta.

Comment: En teoria cualquier version superior a 2008 deberia funcionar http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/ porque no bajas la 2013 o 2015 community

Comment: vale me quedo con la 2015 express a ver si funciona

Comment: No express, **community** ahora trae mas habilitados mas modulos que antes https://www.visualstudio.com/es/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

### Como integrar Qt-MSVC2013 Con Visual Studio en 10 pasos!

---

*Saludos en este apartado te dare los pasos para que puedas tener Visual Studio corriendo con la framework de Qt lista para hacer programas compatibles con Qt desde Visual Studio!*

---

1. Bajate el [Visual Studio 2013 Community](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517284) e instalalo.
2. Bajate el `Qt-5.7.0 MSVC2013`, Para compilar en `x86` [[Click Aqui]](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.7.0.exe), para      compilar en `x64` [[Click Aqui]](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.7.0.exe)
3. Abre el instalador relativo a la version que hayas seleccionado arriba e inicia el proceso de instalacion regular en la ruta predeterminada por el instalador. ****Si modificas la ruta de instalacion predeterminada, favor de tenerlo en cuenta.****
4. Una vez el proceso de instalacion de Qt haya finalizado, ejecuta tu nuevo IDE de *Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition*
5. Dirijete hacia el menu de `Tools -> Extensions and Updates...` y da click en ello, una vez la ventana de `Extensions and Updates` se haya abierto, en la parte izquierda en el navegador selecciona `Online` y en el submenu selecciona `Visual Studio Gallery` Presiona <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> para iniciar una nueva busqueda, luego escribe: `Qt` y te hara una busqueda de los componentes disponibles con nuestro criterio, te aparecera uno en particular con nombre de `QtPackage` dale en `Download` te saldra la ventanita para instalar, dale en `Install` y comenzara a instalar, luego de la instalación te pedira que reinicies el IDE, hazlo.

La instalacion del paquete te pedira que reinicies la instancia de tu IDE, hazlo, luego de que tu IDE reinicie te deberia mostrar una nueva pestaña en la barra de menu asi como muestra la figura a.

> [image: Nueva Pestaña de Qt ya instalada e integrada en Visual Studio!]
>
> Figura A.

Luego de esto...

6. abre la nueva pestaña y dirigete a la ultima opcion: `Qt Options` y da click en ella.
7. en las opciones deberas añadir la ruta de instalacion en la cual se instaló el Qt, (¿Recuerdas la nota en el paso #3?) deberia quedar como se muestra en la figura B.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Figura B. *Note que la ruta de instalacion en mi equipo es diferente*

8. Crea un nuevo proyecto basado en Qt (si las plantillas de desarrollo no te aparecen salta al paso 'A').
9. En el proyecto, dale click derecho y selecciona sus propiedades, selecciona la penultima opcion: `Qt Project Settings` aqui se abrira una nueva ventanita, en dicha ventanita en la ultima opcion llamada: `Version`, selecciona de la caja desplegable, la version que ya hemos instalado anteriormente.
10. Listo!

---

A. *Dirigete a la barra de menu, pestaña `QT5`, selecciona la opcion que dice: `Install Templates and Register Libraries`, si te pide que reinicies hazlo, si aun no ves nada, reinicia tu ordenador.*

---

Saludos cordiales y espero haberte ayudado en algo!